# Google Places API for Android resulting ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-places-api

So the problem I'm stuck on now is how to get a result from Google Places searches when I utilize the AutoComplete method? Currently all that happens is that I get thiserror
`aAutocompletePredictionBuffer{status=Status{statusCode=ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED, resolution=null}}`

Here is my code snippet for how I attempt to do the request. This is based off of examples I found on the internet too.

```
void someMethod(){
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .useDefaultAccount()
                .build();

        client.connect();
}

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> callback = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(client,
                "Chicago",
                googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds,
                null);

        callback.setResultCallback(result ->{
            result.toString();
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I build up the API and then when it connects I do the request. However all I get is this error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that when you're using AutoComplete you cannot use the default zoom of the GoogleMap that shows up. You need to have a project that is focused on a continent or country. So i ended up simply requesting the user's current location, followed by panning the camera over the location to get a viewport so i could get the latlng bounds. (Using handlers to wait)

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();

        client.connect();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(()->{
            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> currentlocation = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(client, null);

            currentlocation.setResultCallback(place -> {


                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.get(0).getPlace().getLatLng(), 10);
                googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);

                handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                    PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> callback = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(client, "Chicago",
                                    googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds, null);

                    callback.setResultCallback(result -> {
                        result.toString();
                    });
                }, 1000);


            });


        }, 1000);
```